# Riddle me this: why does the implicit interface implementation error occur?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface, abstract

Consider the following lines of code:

```
public interface IProduct
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IProductList
{
    string Name { get; }

    IProduct GetValueObject();
}

public abstract class BaseProductList<T> : IProductList where T : class, IProduct, new()
{
    public abstract T GetValueObject();

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This gives me the following warning:
[image: Error 1 ConsoleApplication1.EnumTest.BaseProductList-T- does not implement interface member ConsoleApplication1.EnumTest.IProductList.GetValueObject(). ConsoleApplication1.EnumTest.BaseProductList-T-.GetValueObject() cannot implement ConsoleApplication1.EnumTest.IProductList.GetValueObject() because it does not have the matching return type of ConsoleApplication1.EnumTest.IProduct]

<sub>(Error 1   'ConsoleApplication1.EnumTest.BaseProductList' does not
 implement interface member
 'ConsoleApplication1.EnumTest.IProductList.GetValueObject()'.
 'ConsoleApplication1.EnumTest.BaseProductList.GetValueObject()'
 cannot implement
 'ConsoleApplication1.EnumTest.IProductList.GetValueObject()' because
 it does not have the matching return type of
 'ConsoleApplication1.EnumTest.IProduct'.   \cencibel\homes$\k.bakker\visual
 studio
 2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\EnumTest\Program.cs  29  23  TestApp)</sub>

**But when I add this explicit piece of code, it works:**

```
IProduct IProductList.GetValueObject()
{
    return GetValueObject();
}
```

Why can't .Net figure this one out!?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A method returning `IProduct` is *not* the same as a method returning some-type-implementing-`IProduct`. You're trying to use [*covariant return types*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type) - which .NET doesn't support.

Basically it's similar to this situation:

```
// Doesn't compile
class Foo : ICloneable
{
    public Foo Clone()
    {
        return new Foo();
    }
}
```

Looks good, and allows clients to call `Clone()` and get back a strongly-typed value - but it doesn't implement the interface. This isn't supported in .NET, and never has been - the generics in your code are just another example of the same problem.

Comment: Wow... now I know what it feels like when I'm trying to talk Spanish to somebody. Got some reading material for me?

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker: Have edited a link into the answer. Basically this isn't specific to generics - it's just a feature (covariant return types) which isn't supported by .NET in general, and never has been.

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker: The link wasn't there when you added the comment :)

Comment: Could this ever be a .Net feature? Why would you not support something like this?

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker: Me? I don't work on .NET :) I suspect it could cause some interesting backward compatibility issues if it were introduced now - but yes, it would have been nice to have had it from the start.

Comment: Reading material :) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one.aspx

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker: People ask us for this feature -- covariance on overriding virtual return types -- all the time. (Strangely enough, no one ever asks for *contravariance* on parameter types.) We're not going to do it, sorry. It is not supported by the runtime, it introduces new forms of the brittle base class failure, and we have more important features to work on. I don't hate the feature -- I'd use it if I had it -- but I have been in many language design meetings over the years where we've decided to not do it, so it's unlikely to ever get to the top of the list of important features.

Comment: Hm... JDK5.0 seems to have some form of covariance. Is a c# wishlist of important features publicly available?

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker: Yes, Java introduced covariant return types, but there are various other differences between Java and C# which I suspect make this more of a breaking change. I'm inclined to trust the judgement of Eric and the rest of the team here - the effort involved isn't worth the benefit.